# How to retrieve file from FTP server in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to download files from FTP server to mobile devices but could not find any plugins to do so. How to connect devices to FTP Server and download the files using Flutter?

Comment: Did you try https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_downloader ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SSH](https://pub.dev/packages/ssh) library

```
//Connect SFTP: #
  await client.connectSFTP();
//List directory: #
  var array = await client.sftpLs("/home");
```